# Google API - "Active session is invalid. Error code: 4"

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am trying to access the Google Drive API through Oauth2 and have encountered an error that does not yield any results when searching.

**Here is my code.**

```
require "oauth2"
require "google/apis/gmail_v1"
require "google/apis/drive_v3"
require "googleauth"

token = { 
    access_token: ...,
    refresh_token: ...,
}

def get_gmail_service(token)
  service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
  service.authorization = oauth_authorization(token,
    [ Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_READONLY, Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_LABELS]
  )
  service.request_options.retries = 3
  service
end

def get_drive_service(token)
  service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
  service.authorization = oauth_authorization(token,
    [ Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE ]
  )
  service.request_options.retries = 3
  service
end

def oauth_authorization token, scope
  Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
    authorization_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    token_credential_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    client_id: ENV["G_CLIENT_ID"],
    client_secret: ENV["G_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    access_token: token["access_token"],
    refresh_token: token["refresh_token"],
    scope: scope
  })
end

get_gmail_service(token).create_user_label('me', 'test') #=> WORKS
get_drive_service(token).list_files #=> ERROR
```

**This is the error that I get.**

```
Google::Apis::AuthorizationError:Unauthorized
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Active session is invalid. Error code: 4",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

From all searching it would appear the token has expired but I think the tokens are not expired because they also work at the same time on the Gmail Api.

**What have I tried?**

1. I enabled Drive API.
2. Made sure OAuth2 Scope for the consent screen are `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',`
3. Tried using the DriveV2 instead of V3 client
4. Hours of searching for a similar error. There are almost no results for `"Active session is invalid. Error code: 4"`
5. Asked ChatGPT

Comment: Are you **100% sure** the token is valid? What is the value of `scope` in this instance?

Comment: Are you using a Google Workspace account in your setup?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure it is valid, but how else can I check? Scope is `['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']`

Comment: Yes Exactly, Google Workspace

Comment: @stellard Please share the decoded version of the token using jwt.io (keep all the values the same but anything personal, just change to something else with the same data type e.g. personal name to 'john')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 403 response is caused by Google Drive being disabled by policy, which can be done [per Organizational Unit](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182442) or [via Group membership](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9050643?hl=en). That 403 response is distinct from the 401 response which actually comes back with a *helpful* `details` payload when *just* the [access Google Drive with the Drive SDK API](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6105699?hl=en) is turned of, and not Drive itself. I don't believe Super Admin credentials are subject to that restriction, but Google Workspace is a mysterious beast and so it's *possible*

It is a terrible error, but thankfully is is unique enough that it will hopefully lead folks to this question

To the very best of my knowledge there is no way to know in advance that those policies are in place except by calling [the `GET /about` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/about/get) (or a similar "should always work" request) and rescuing the 401 or 403 response to know the situation per User